# How to manage textlabel height by parent view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some issue. I trie to make custom table header sections. Here is my code:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeader = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 36))

        sectionHeader.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1215686277, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.4235294163, alpha: 1)

        tableView.backgroundColor = colors.background

        let headerName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: sectionHeader.frame.size.height))

        headerName.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        headerName.text = sectionHeaders[section]
        headerName.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)
        headerName.clipsToBounds = true

        sectionHeader.addSubview(headerName)

        return sectionHeader
    }
```

And here is result:
[image]

With blue and yellow color i marked and noticed, that label height not the same as headerview. Can some one help me how manage textlabel height to header view height, and how to align text verticaly

Comment: Have you used `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> label height not the same as headerview

At first you should setup height of your section header:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 36.0
}
```

Based on `height: 36` from  `let sectionHeader = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 36))`

> how to align text verticaly

```
headerName.textAlignment = .center
```